# Is it necessary for a bank to have database ports open?

Tags: mysql, port

Suppose we have a client-server architecture for a bank. The client will, of course, send a post request to the bank asking to deposit/withdraw money, but the server will be making all of the database queries. Therefore, is it necessary for the bank to have these ports open since the client shouldn't be making a request to this port? Suppose the bank has port 3306 (MySQL) open within these situations.

**I have noticed some banking websites have this port open when using nmap for funsies and was wondering why?**

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question, perhaps it's something for https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If external communication is a via a HTTP-based API then there should be no need for a database port as well. But maybe it's just for some testing or POC or something. I doubt a bank is using MySQL for anything serious. Can you actually reach a mysql server if you try to connect on these ports?

Comment: To be able to communicate with a program, it is required that there is an available communication channel. That channel could be reachable using a port, a unix domain socket, ... . But you won't want to make this communcation channel to be reachable for everyone, so you would restrict the reachability (listening only on a local IP subnet or only for certain IPs, limiting access to a certain system user/group)

Comment: @ADyson You may have too much faith in the purity of banks… ;)

Comment: @deceze I was more thinking of the probability that everything they do is still based on 80s mainframes and they would never dare to touch anything so "modern" or, heaven forbid, open-source :-p. But maybe for their web platforms or something I guess. Or maybe it's one of the new online-only banks...or maybe they just have no idea what they're doing. I'll leave it to the reader to decide which is most likely...